# WinForms temporary disable vertical scrollbar in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, panel, mschart

I have MSChart control within Panel in my form. Panel has AutoScroll property set to True. Once the chart gets too big - user is able to scroll through it.

Once user presses Ctrl+MouseWheel I am enabling zoom in/out to the chart area. Currently on MouseWheel - both Panel and Chart are scrolling. How do I disable Panel scrollbars at the time when Chart is handling scrolling events?

After disabling AutoScroll property Panel is moving scroll to the top and hiding vertical scrollbar - so this is not what I want:

```
void Chart_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control == true)
    {
         (Parent as Panel).AutoScroll = false;
    }
}

void Chart_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control == false)
    {
        (Parent as Panel).AutoScroll = true;
    }
}
```

I would like Panel scrollbar to "freeze" when chart is zooming (ctrl+mousewheel) and activate when chart is idle (mousewheel). Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mousewheel bubbling up in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983757/mousewheel-bubbling-up-in-winforms)

Comment: Perfect - thanks ! Though I have other issue with focusing the control in panel. Once I try to call Focus on chart, panel is scrolling to the top. I think this is because chart boundaries are at the top of panel. Any ideas how to disable scrolling on Focus?