# Preview mouse wheel on AutoScroll Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, autoscroll

Let's have a large `Control` (whose `Size` is given externally and "cannot" be altered). This `Control` is contained in `Panel`. There is very useful feature `Panel.Autoscroll = true`, which enables comfortable scrolling of the large `Control` with zero work.

There is one problem: The `Control` needs to handle the `MouseWheel` (and it gets the events as expected - it is focused on mouse enter). Ufortunately the `Panel` **also** captures the same mouse wheel events and uses them for scrolling. This is not desirable for the cases the `Control` "consumes" the events.

I cannot find a standard way to handle this. Even the `Panel.Scroll` event is called only on mouse click scrolls, not mouse wheel scrolls.

**Is there a natural WinForms friendly way how to temporarily instruct the `Panel` with `AutoScroll` set to true not to process the mouse wheel events for scrolling?**

Comment: The problem is that the control does *not* consume the event.  It uses the event but then lets it bubble to its parent.  Backgrounder [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6987339/17034).

Comment: Yes, I knew it doesn't, but as there is no flag in the MouseEventArgs to signal it, it raised my question. How (the hell ;) you do know it actually IS HandledMouseEventArgs (and thus it contains the consumed flag)? It's just enough to cast it (safely) and set the Handled for the case of consumption. Thanks!

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs

Comment: Wasn't aware of this. Even better than ILSpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your panel with the AutoScroll = True with this version, which comments out the base call to the OnMouseWheel method:

```
public class PanelEx: Panel {
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e) {
    //base.OnMouseWheel(e);
  }
}
```

or as Hans points out from his [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987339/719186), set the Handled property to true in your control:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e) {
  base.OnMouseWheel(e);
  ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't stop the bubbling, now the form scrolls :)  Proper fix is ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;

Comment: No need to derive new Panel. It's enough to cast it in the default implementation inside the mouse wheel event handler.