# Disable Windows 10 "scroll inactive windows" in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, windows-10, mousewheel

I have a question regarding C#, Winforms and "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" in Windows 10.

I have a flow layout panel, which i dynamically fill with custom controls. 
The controls have a zoom in zoom out feature that is controlled by the mouse wheel.

When the number of controls exceed the flow layout panel size i got AutoScroll = true, so the panel gets a vertical scroll bar. I do not want to scroll the panel with the mouse wheel, i want the user to manually do it.

Everything works fine in Windows 7, but in Windows 10, if the user has the "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" turned on, when the mouse is over a control and the user uses the mouse wheel, the control zooms in or out, but the panel also scrolls.

I debugged, and i found that Win10 scrolls the panel even before the form/panel's MouseWheel event.

**How can I disable the "Scroll inactive.." temporarily in my code ? or at least disable its behavior?**

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983757/mousewheel-bubbling-up-in-winforms/6987339#6987339

Answer (score 0):

The only thing comes to my mind to disable the behavior is to check whether the window is `TopMost` or lost focus.
This can be done by using the `form.TopMost` property **or** the `Activated` and `Deactivate` events.
Using the **events**:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Deactivate += Form1_Deactivate;
        this.Activated += Form1_Activated;
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)//The form gained focus
    {
        panel1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)// The form lost focus
    {
        panel1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

These will work just fine but using some controls it will make them change appearance on some OS. 
If you don't mind that, great.
If you do, you should go for the same concept using the events only disabling the scroll itself once the form lost focus and enabling it when its regained.

Cheers.

Comment: You could also store that activated/deactivated status in a boolean (or plain check it? Shouldn't there be some kind of way to check it directly?) and check that in a scroll event handler that cancels the event by immediately setting it 'handled'.