# Controlling horizontal scrollbar of FlowLayoutPanel programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I'm trying to implement <kbd>Shift</kbd> + MouseWheel to perform horizontal scrolling in a panel. The vertical scroll (without pressing shift key) works fine. But the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + MouseWheel scrolls both horizontally and vertically.

How do I fix it?

```
if (shiftKeyPressed)
{   
    if (IsGoUp && this.fLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value > scrollValue)
    {
         this.fLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value -= scrollValue;
    }
    if (!IsGoUp && this.fLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value < this.fLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum - scrollValue)
    {
         this.fLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value += scrollValue;
    }
}
```

So far, I tried recording the vertical scroll value and setting it afterwards but didn't work. Probably I should stop the scroll event firing.

Comment: @Sinatr WinForms

Comment: You are doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.  A blind guess is that you haven't heard of the [HandledMouseEventsArgs class before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987339/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant you are right...